# Using Multiple Cases in a Switch Statement

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, switch-statement

I'm trying to use a switch statement on a three button action where the user can select between morning, afternoon and evening times. I'm wanting to change the background and text colors based on what button is selected.

Right now my buttons are not changing based on tap, what do I need to do in order to get this working? Also, how can I use like tag 10 and tag 20 in one of the cases? Thank you.

// My Buttons

```
    private lazy var morningButton: TimeButton = {
        let button = TimeButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Morning", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 14)
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var afternoonButton: TimeButton = {
        let button = TimeButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Afternoon", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 14)
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var eveningButton: TimeButton = {
        let button = TimeButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Evening", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 14)
        return button
    }()
```

// Switch Statement

```
@objc func timeButtonsTapped(_ sender: TimeButton) {
        
        switch sender.tag {
        case 10:
            morningButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
            morningButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            afternoonButton.backgroundColor = .white
            afternoonButton.setTitleColor(.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
            eveningButton.backgroundColor = .white
            eveningButton.setTitleColor(.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
        case 20:
            afternoonButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
            afternoonButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            morningButton.backgroundColor = .white
            morningButton.setTitleColor(.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
            eveningButton.backgroundColor = .white
            eveningButton.setTitleColor(.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
        case 30:
            eveningButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
            eveningButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            morningButton.backgroundColor = .white
            morningButton.setTitleColor(.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
            afternoonButton.backgroundColor = .white
            afternoonButton.setTitleColor(.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
        case 10 & 20:
            morningButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
            morningButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            afternoonButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
            afternoonButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            eveningButton.backgroundColor = .white
            eveningButton.setTitleColor(.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
        case 10 & 30:
            morningButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
            morningButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            eveningButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
            eveningButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            afternoonButton.backgroundColor = .white
            afternoonButton.setTitleColor(.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
        case 20 & 30:
            afternoonButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
            afternoonButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            eveningButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
            eveningButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            morningButton.backgroundColor = .white
            morningButton.setTitleColor(.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
        case 10 & 20 & 30:
            morningButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
            morningButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            afternoonButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
            afternoonButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            eveningButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
            eveningButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        default:
            morningButton.backgroundColor = .white
            morningButton.setTitleColor(.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
            afternoonButton.backgroundColor = .white
            afternoonButton.setTitleColor(.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
            eveningButton.backgroundColor = .white
            eveningButton.setTitleColor(.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
        }
        
    }
```

// My Function

```
fileprivate func configureUI() {

        morningButton.tag = 10
        morningButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        afternoonButton.tag = 20
        afternoonButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        eveningButton.tag = 30
        eveningButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        morningButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timeButtonsTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        afternoonButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timeButtonsTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        eveningButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timeButtonsTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `case 10 & 20`? `timeButtonsTapped` will be called once for each button pressed, so if the user presses two buttons at the same time, it will be called twice. Do you want to distinguish between "pressing 2 buttons at the same time" and "pressing 2 buttons one after the other"?

Comment: Like I want like the morning and afternoon buttons to change based on if users tap both one after another. In other words, the morning and afternoon buttons will have purple backgrounds and white text if tapped.

Comment: Then you don't need to set the other buttons' background to to white in each case (just set the desired button background to purple), and you only need the first 3 cases.

Comment: Okay, then the next problem is my targets aren't firing. Should I be using UITapGestureRecognizers?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to spread the button coloring logic all over your view controller. It results in lots of code duplication and poor maintainability in the future.

The UIButton has an `isSelected` property, you can use it in this particular case to save the state of a button. Also I would suggest moving all of the colors into the button's subclass so that the client doesn't have to worry about them. The button should be responsible for switching its colors.

Here's what the TimeButton class would look like:

```swift
class TimeButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }
    
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            updateBackgroundColor()
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private
    private func setup() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        setTitleColor(.systemPurple, for: .selected)
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 14)
        updateBackgroundColor()
    }
    
    private func updateBackgroundColor() {
        backgroundColor = isSelected ? .white : .systemPurple
    }
}
```

Your view controller now should look like this:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var morningButton: TimeButton = {
        let button = TimeButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Morning", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didSelectButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var afternoonButton: TimeButton = {
        let button = TimeButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Afternoon", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didSelectButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var eveningButton: TimeButton = {
        let button = TimeButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Evening", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didSelectButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    @objc private func didSelectButton(_ button: TimeButton) {
        button.isSelected = !button.isSelected
        // do some additional stuff if needed
    }
}
```

Note the `type: .custom` in the button's init - this will disable the default button styling when it gets selected.

If you want to get the value of some button - just refer to its `isSelected` property:

```swift
let shouldUseMorningTime = morningButton.isSelected
```

Comment: Also, ideally we should use background image instead of background color. Then the switching would be even simpler. I am not sure if it's a good idea for the button to manage `isSelected` internally using an internal action. That should be normally done externally.

Comment: @Sulthan you're correct, thanks for the comment. Moved the actions setup to the view controller.